# Grails list max results

Tags: grails

I have the controller below that returns 100+ results and I want to be able to only pass 10 results with the json call and some sort of method that if more results are desired another request should be made but I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

**Here's an except of my controller**

```
def list(){
   def results = Domain.list(max: 10)
   withFormat {
       json (render results as JSON)
   }

}
```

Can someone point me in the write direction where I can read on documentation or see sample codes that might do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Go through this .....http://www.jellyfishtechnologies.com/working-of-grails-pagination/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default scaffolding templates would be a good place to look as they show how to do pagination in the `list` action.  How about this:

```
def list(){
   // max 10 unless something else was requested
   if(!params.max) params.max=10
   def results = Domain.list(params)
   withFormat {
       json (render results as JSON)
   }

}
```

To request the next page of results you'd use `.../list?offset=10&max=10`, for the next use `offset=20`, etc.

Refer docs for [`list()`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/list.html) method on how pagination parameters work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
def c = Domain.createCriteria()
def results = c.list(max: 10, offset: 10) {    
    order("some", "desc")
}
withFormat {
    json { render results as JSON } 
}
```

[Refer](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html)

Comment: I tried this but I couldn't get anything more than the first 10 values. Offsetting didn't work